# How to perform multiple API calls inside ComponentDidMount using fetch in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my componentDidMount function I call AsyncStorage to get some saved value and then make a GET request and fetch data like below:

```
componentDidMount() {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then(value => {
    const url = 'my url';
    console.log('token:' + value)
    return fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'token': 'abcd',
          'jwt': value
        })
      })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          dataSource: responseJson,
          isLoading: false,
          getValue: value
        })
      })
      .catch((Error) => {
        console.log(Error)
      })
  })
}
```

Now, I need to make another GET request. Suppose if I want to make the same request again in this function , how can I do that?

Comment: Make this a function and call that multiple times from componentDidMount?

Comment: you can use setInterval inside the componentDidiMount to make api call in desired the timeInterval.

Comment: I tried the suggestion from @DTul and it works

Comment: @MohammedAshfaq, thanks but I don't have much idea about setInterval. Will you please elaborate the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it very easily from the suggested comments. I did the API call part in two different functions and then called these two functions inside ComponentDidMount like below code-

```
 getFirstApiResposnse() {

  AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then(value => {
    const url = 'my url';
    console.log('token:'+ value)
   return fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      'token': 'abcd',
      'jwt': value
    })
  })
   .then((response)=> response.json() )
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: responseJson,
      isLoading: false,
      getValue: value

    })
  })
  .catch((Error) => {
    console.log(Error)
  });

  }

  )

};


getSecondApiResponse() {

  AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then(value => {
    const url = 'my url';
    console.log('token:'+ value)
   return fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
      'token': 'abcd',
      'jwt': value
    })
  })
   .then((response)=> response.json() )
  .then((responseJson) => {
   console.log('####:'+responseJson.cat_note)
    this.setState({

      isLoading: false,
      getValue: value,
    })
  })
  .catch((Error) => {
    console.log(Error)
  });

  }

  )

}

  componentDidMount() {

    this.getFirstApiResponse();
    this.getSecondApiResponse();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Promise.all(). Which comes handy with multiple requests. Also, we can use helper library such as async and use its forEach, waterFall, series, parallel, etc methods depending on project needs. These things make our code more readable and scalable.